# Symfony 2 Entity status parameter change when certain datetime passes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I've got an GameEvent Entity

among parameters it has a **status** which is a small int to indicate well... the state of the Event.

0 - just started

1 - taking place

2 - finished

I've got a datetime object storred in **event_start_time**
the GameEvent status should change from 0 to 1 when the curent date passes **event_start_time**. How should I go on about this.

I want to filter the entity by this status entry in a query builder later on.

Is there any way to automate the Start of the Game other than using a command with cron to search for matches to start every 5 minutes or so?

How can I go about this?

Or should I just filter out the GameEvents by

- Date before now ( status 0)
- Date After now but lets say **closed** == false
- Date After now but **closed** == true

I welcome any ideas because I don't know what to search for

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a secondary **mapped** field in your entity that does that: the value of that hypothetical field should change over time, and that should suggest to you that it's not something that you want to have stored on a DB.

Maybe you can have an helper method like `isStarted(): bool` and `isFinished()`, and nothing else.

If you want to filter it by a particular status using a `QueryBuilder`, I would suggest you to create a specific method in your repository, something like this:

```
class GameEventRepository extends BaseRepository
{
   public function findAllInProgress()
   {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
        $qb->andWhere('e.event_start_time <= :now');
        $qb->setParameter('now', new \DateTime());
        $qb->andWhere('e.closed = 0');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
   }
}
```